# Translate Standard Tab Dashboards in Other Language

Tags: customization, translation

Here I want to Translate Standard Tab "Dashboards" in german language.for that i check following path...

**Customize->TabNames & Labels -> Rename Tabes and Labels
But In that there is no standard Tab DashBoards.....**

Whenever i am logging into portal except German language,there is translation of the "Dashboards" tab,but in the case of German language there is no translation of the Dashboards tab.

**Actually i want to translate 'Dashboards' tab in german language in portal...where can i find this kind of translation..**

here is the picture of the 'dashboards' standard tab in chinese(Simplified) language,that was translated....

[image]

Now see the picture of the 'Dashboards' standard tab in german language,that was not translated.....

[image]

So here what can i do to translate in german?Please help me to find the solutions...

Comment: Hello It's urgent please some one help me...if it is possible...

Comment: There is an unimplemented idea relating to this https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ad21AAA so that is not promising. Have you explored the features of the "Translation Workbench" (https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=entering_translated_terms.htm&language=en_US) to see if that has the required capability?

Comment: Thanks for your Answer....but sir this Dashboards tab was translated in chinese,japanese but it was not translated in german.....here i want to find the exact location where the translation was happened?..so i can translated in german also.....

Comment: Hello Sir now i post the image of the 'Dashboard' tab...in that chinese language translated but in german that was not translated....please picture above and help me....

Comment: Have you checked that in German they do not just use the English term? If you are sure it should be translated, you should raise a case with salesforce and sometime in the future they may fix it; they may have a workaround to offer meanwhile.